# Changing the Rendering Of A JasperReports Chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I'm trying to change the render type of a Chart within JasperReports. I've got the Chart Customizer property set correctly, the class can be found [and hit when debugging] However the changes requested aren't made when the report is rendered.

The JRChartCustomizer class is:

```
public class PriceGraph implements JRChartCustomizer {

    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

        Shape shp = new Rectangle2D.Double(-0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
        renderer.setBaseShape(shp);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.yellow);
        renderer.setBasePaint(Color.green);
    }
}
```

Has anyone hit this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `plot.setRenderer(...)` to actually apply the renderer to the chart.

My code looks like this:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
    Shape shp = new Rectangle2D.Double(-0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0, shp);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.yellow);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, Boolean.TRUE);
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, Boolean.FALSE);
    plot.setRenderer(0, renderer);
}
```

Comment: Why is this accepted as the answer then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140657/how-to-display-bar-value-for-each-bar-in-a-bar-graph

Comment: I added plot.setRenderer(renderer), and Its still generating the different shapes from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701749/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-shape-size-in-a-jasperreports-chart

Comment: There's a few other differences between your code and mine. I use the concrete renderer class instead of the interface, I set the shape and the renderer for a particular series, and I call `setSeriesShapesVisible(...)` to make sure the shapes are shown. See the changes above.

Comment: The problem was each datapoint was configured to a new series. Changing that fixed the issue with the custom shape etc. Also afterward the code didn't need the setRenderer