# How to customize bar chart labels in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

I have a bar chart as follows

[image]

I want to append some text to the labels so they would look like
2010 B 
2011 C
2012 D

How can i achieve this? I know that we can write BarChartCustomizer but not sure how to get the labels for a particular bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the data for the labels come from?

Comment: Did you try to implement your own *JRChartCustomizer*? You can read the *Chart Customizer and Chart Theme* topic of [*JasperReports Ultimate Guide*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Comment: You can also read [How to display bar value for each bar in a bar graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5140657/876298) post on *SO*

Comment: You can also read [this posts](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/tag/bar-chart/) by *Matthew Dahlman* aka *mdahlman*

Comment: Finally ended up using groovy expressions in iReport to change the labels based on some conditions

Comment: @OpenSourceRulzz It is better to post your solution as an answer